# Ranking a list of tuples with same values?

Tags: python-3.x, tuples, python-3.7, ranking

I want to rank this list of tuples:

```
[("Blueberries", 1), ("Strawberries", 2), ("Apple", 3), ("Apple", 4), ("Orange", 2)]
```

It should output:

```
[("Apple", 4), ("Apple", 3), ("Strawberries", 2), ("Orange", 2), ("Blueberries", 1)]
```

A dictionary works great without duplicate values. Is there any other way I could approach this? Or is there a way I could do this with a dictionary? I'm completely lost.

Comment: `sorted(list_of_tuples, key=lambda tup: (tup[1], tup[0]), reverse=True)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort a list using the `key=` parameter to define which function you want to use for the sort. In this case, it looks like you want to sort based off of the second item in the tuple, so:

```py
l = [("Blueberries", 1), ("Strawberries", 2), ("Apple", 3), ("Apple", 4), ("Orange", 2)]
sorted_list = sorted(l,key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
```

You can do this without using a lambda function by just defining that function with a name.

```py
def my_sort_func(item):
    return item[1]

sorted_list = sorted(l, key=my_sort_func, reverse=True)
```

Comment: Is there a way I could use this without lambda? I can't use it for this particular question.

Comment: you could define that function with a name, but that doesn't change the spirit of things much. that is, you could also have `def sort_func(item): return item[1]` and then you'd have `key=sort_func`.

Comment: you should mark the answer complete / upvote it so that others can quickly see that it worked. glad it helped